# Unable to access @Value in configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({
        "com.informatica.cloud.errorutil.springhandler",
        "com.informatica.cloud.service.cdiclairerecommendation",
        "com.informatica.cloud.commons.shutdown"
})
@PropertySource("classpath:cdiclairerecommendation-service-application.properties")
@EnableMicroserviceVersion
@EnableMicroserviceHealth
@EnableCircuitBreaker

public class CDIClaireRecommendationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Value("${ids.baseUrl}")
    private String idsBaseUrl;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  
        String CMS_SERVICE_URI = idsBaseUrl;
        
        return application.sources(CDIClaireRecommendationApplication.class).listeners(new ApplicationStartingEventListener());
      
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SpringApplicationBuilder(CDIClaireRecommendationApplication.class)
                .properties("spring.config.name:cdiclairerecommendation-service-application")
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

I have added the value of ids.baseUrl in the application.properties

ids.baseUrl=http://localhost:16006/identity-service

When I am trying to access the value of ids.baseUrl in configure function, it is coming null. Can somebody please help?

Comment: is this path and property name correct? `@PropertySource("classpath:cdiclairerecommendation-service-application.properties")
`

Comment: @Vimukthi_R yes property name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that **`application.properties`** has `ids.baseUrl` if not this is not presented in `cdiclairerecommendation-service-application.properties`.

Other causes might be you are creating class object with `new` keyword but not with `autowiring` strategy (it will get visibility of spring managed properties).

We can also add two files like below to get the properties into current component

```
@PropertySource({
    "classpath:cdiclairerecommendation-service-application.properties",
    "classpath:application.properties" 
})
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: Per what I say in my answer, the problem is not that the property `ids.baseUrl` is not defined.  Also, I don't see `new CDIClaireRecommendationApplication` being called anywhere, and `CDIClaireRecommendationApplication.class` is being passed into the builder class, so I assume that Spring is creating the instance of this class and so autowiring should be occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the way you're building your Spring app, but my guess is that your `configure` method is being called too early, before the Spring Context has been fully built and all of the autowiring performed.

What I would do in this case is have your `CDIClaireRecommendationApplication`  class implement `CommandLineRunner`, implement the `run` method, and in that method try accessing your `idsBaseUrl` variable.  If I'm right, then the value will be autowired into place by the time the `run` method runs, and you will know that the problem is due to the order in which things are happening during initialization.

I don't think that the problem can be due to the specifics of the particular property you're trying to wire in.  If that property did not exist at the time that Spring were trying to autowire it, then I believe that you would get an error message from Spring and your initialization would fail.

UPDATE: I just confirmed what I said about the property value not being defined.  I changed one of my app's @Value annotations to refer to a non-existent property, and my app failed to start with the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xxxx' in value "${xxxx}"
```

This tells me that your problem is that either that field isn't being autowired at all, or it is, but after your `configure` method is being called.